Xamarin.Google.Android.Play.App.Update package issue
I have implemented in-app updates for android in .NET MAUI using this package
<ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="9.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter" Version="5.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes" Version="5.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics" Version="5.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.61.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.70" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.70" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-android'">
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging" Version="123.0.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Android.Play.App.Update" Version="2.1.0.10" />
</ItemGroup>

But when building the project this error is coming
Error JAVA0000: Error in /.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm/1.4.0.5/buildTransitive/net8.0-android34.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class:
Type androidx.collection.ArrayMapKt is defined multiple times: /.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm/1.4.0.5/buildTransitive/net8.0-android34.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class, /.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx/1.2.0.9/buildTransitive/net6.0-android31.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-ktx.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class
Compilation failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm/1.4.0.5/buildTransitive/net8.0-android34.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar
androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:135)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.main(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:5)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm/1.4.0.5/buildTransitive/net8.0-android34.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class
at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_8.2.33.java:0)
at com.android.tools.r8.T.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:5)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:82)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:32)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:31)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.b(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:2)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:42)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:13)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:40)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:122)
... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Type androidx.collection.ArrayMapKt is defined multiple times: /.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm/1.4.0.5/buildTransitive/net8.0-android34.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class, /.nuget/packages/xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx/1.2.0.9/buildTransitive/net6.0-android31.0/../../jar/androidx.collection.collection-ktx.jar:androidx/collection/ArrayMapKt.class
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Q2.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:21)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.D2.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:54)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.D2.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:10)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2048)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.D2.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:6)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.m4$a.d(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:6)
at com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:61)
at com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:12)
at com.android.tools.r8.dex.c.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:9)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:45)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:17)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.c(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:69)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.S0.a(R8_8.2.33_429c93fd24a535127db6f4e2628eb18f2f978e02f99f55740728d6b22bef16dd:28)
... 6 more
(JAVA0000)
Can someone tell me, what exactly is the issue and a fix for that?
This issue came when I installed
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.Android.Play.App.Update" Version="2.1.0.10" />```

**NOTE: For lower versions of the Xamarin.Google.Android.Play.App.Update package, I'm not getting this error, but not able to use IInstallStateUpdatedListener (for lower versions)**


xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx is dependent on xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm. try adding it to the project, perhaps it helps maui to understand which version to use ?

The underlying issue is Type androidx.collection.ArrayMapKt is defined multiple times. Somehow class androidx.collection.ArrayMapKt is added twice from the transitive dependencies. You will have to go through your dependencies.
